# virtualbox mail server postfix+dovecot

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, postfix, dovecot, vps

I'm setting up a mail server(ubuntu14.4 serverX64) for development/testing purposes (using virtualBox bridged-mode) and I  just finished this [tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-nginx-bind-mysql-php-postfix-dovecot-and-ispconfig3-p6) 
 and everything seams to work.
Now I'm not able to login/ use the email service using either:

- Thunderbird client
- Squirrelmail

with Thunderbird it says: login to server failed  and on squirrel "Unknown user or password incorrect"., 
What am'I missing?

this is my postfix main.cf

```
#See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.ely.net
#myhostname = 192.168.1.100
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.ely.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain
#mydestination = 192.168.1.100, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
message_size_limit = 0
```

if I do a nslookup from the server(virtualbox-ubuntuServer14.04X64) I get

```
root@mail:/etc/nginx# nslookup mail.ely.net
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mail.ely.net    canonical name = mail.netidentity.com.cust.hostedemail.com.
Name:   mail.netidentity.com.cust.hostedemail.com
Address: 216.40.42.5
```

from the host computer(ubuntu desktop 14.04x64)

```
main@main:~$ nslookup mail.ely.net
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mail.ely.net    canonical name = mail.netidentity.com.cust.hostedemail.com.
Name:   mail.netidentity.com.cust.hostedemail.com
Address: 216.40.42.5
```

and this is completely right cause is a virtualmachine and is looking at the one outside the lan

now in ispconfig  mail-queue logs I have this interesting thing :

```
Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
C73EE221A5A 2545 Wed Aug 6 01:31:51 mailman-bounces@mail.ely.net
(lost connection with mx.netidentity.com.cust.hostedemail.com[216.40.42.4] while receiving the initial server greeting)
postmaster@ely.net
```

so apparently the issue here is about IPs because its looking a the real mail.ely.net host not my dummy server... so questions arise:

1. is it possible to send-receive email from/to the ouside world i.e gmail/yahoo and make it work like a personal mail server.
2. how can I manage change the conf so that i would place nicely with the outside world
3. why Im getting or how to resolve the problem of the user not found/login issues after finishing the tutorial mentioned above.